# How can I make a compiled MATLAB application check for updates?

Tags: matlab, compilation, auto-update

I have made some open-source software in the MATLAB programming language that other researchers are beginning to use. So that they can run this software without needing to purchase a MATLAB license, I compile the program as a standalone app (.exe) using the MATLAB Compiler (i.e., the `deploytool` command). I am still frequently updating the code to fix bugs and add features and would like to add the ability to have the app automatically (or manually) check for updates to itself.

Any advice on how to do this through MATLAB code or general strategies that I might be able to implement into MATLAB indirectly (e.g., through command line calls) would be appreciated.

Additional information:

- I am using MATLAB R2016a 64-bit Windows version.
- I am hosting the software and source code on [CodePlex](http://carma.codeplex.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off Sam Robert's idea to download a webpage and then parse it as a string, this is the solution I ended up going with. In case it isn't clear, I download an RSS feed that includes a reverse-chronological list of software versions. I then parse the RSS feed as a string for the first occurrence of my software's name followed by v (i.e., "CARMA v"), since I know that the RSS feed will always include a version number after this text and that the first occurrence will always be the most recent. I convert that version number from string to double and compare it to the current version number. If the current version is smaller than the newest version number, I prompt the user to visit the website.

```
rss = urlread('http://carma.codeplex.com/project/feeds/rss?ProjectRSSFeed=codeplex%3a%2f%2frelease%2fcarma');
index = strfind(rss,'CARMA v');
newest = str2double(rss(index(1)+7:index(1)+11));
current = 13.00;
if current < newest
     choice = questdlg(sprintf('CARMA has detected that an update is available.\nOpen download page?'),'CARMA','Yes','No','Yes');
     switch choice
          case 'Yes'
               web('http://carma.codeplex.com/releases/','-browser');
          end
     delete(handles.figure_launcher);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yair Altman wrote a [tool](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39993-checkversion-check-for-a-newer-file-version-on-the-file-exchange) for people who release applications on the MATLAB Central File Exchange. It checks the File Exchange to see whether a new version of the tool is available, and prompts the user to download it. I believe the way it works is to download the web page for the File Exchange submission into a string, parse the text of the web page to extract the latest version number of the submission, and then respond appropriately if it's newer.

You might be able to take a look through the code, and modify it so that it parses the corresponding text of your CodePlex page.